# One prompt code is working while the other does not

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to coding. When I execute the code below, it works;

```
let age = prompt('How old are you?', );

alert(`You are ${age} years old.`);
```

But when I try this; it doesn't work;

```
let name = prompt('What's your name?', );
                  
alert(`Okay ${name}`);
```

Where is the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: i think it because of quotes try with double quotes

Comment: let name = prompt('What's your name?', )

Comment: Use a proper code editor and look at the colors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape the inner '

```
let name = prompt('What\'s your name?');
```

or

```
let name = prompt("What's your name?");
```

if You want to have a default value preset (kindof placeholder)
then use as second parameter that string value

```
let name = prompt('What\'s your name?', '...here Your name');
```

another option is to use template literals, but does not makes sense if You dont consume variables inside it.

```
let name = prompt(`What's your name?`, '...here Your name'); // nope
var kind = 'user'
let name1 = prompt(`What's your ${kind}name? `, `...here Your ${kind}name`); // all good
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in using single quotes and the english language. When you have an apostrophe in your word the use double quotes `"` or backticks `` ` ``  to create a string.

```
let name = prompt("What's your name?");
```

Also there was a trainling `,` comma after the string that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

In the second code snippet the string passed to prompt also contains `'` so it don't work. Use template literals when you want to use `'` or `"` as part of string

```js
let name = prompt(`What's your name?`);           
alert(`Okay ${name}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

`let name = prompt('What\'s your name?', );`

---

You have to escape single quote

Answer (score 0):

```
let name = prompt('What's your name?', ); // this line of code has confusing single quot in it
```

It should be look like this

```
let name = prompt("What's your name?", )
```

or this

```
let name = prompt(`What's your name?`, )
```

or also this will be fine

```
let name = prompt('What\'s your name?', )
```